# Ada - How to generate a list of package variables from GNAT Pro Studio?

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-studio

I'd like to use the xref information from a GPS Ada project to generate lists of the variables defined for each package spec and body.  I need to exclude any variables defined inside of subprograms.

I can see this information in GPS's "Project View" which shows the literals, package, pragmas, types, and variables defined in each file.  However, the information is not selectable for cut/paste.  How do I generate this in text form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPS is customised using Python. The provided scripts are in `{installation}/share/gps/library`; it looks as though `unused_entities.py` might be a good start. Or, there's a chapter on "Customizing and Extending GPS" in the GPS documentation.

[Edit]

Or, even better, look at the example `globals.py` in `{installation}/share/examples/gps/python`. A quick poke through the documentation (accessed in GPS via Help/Python extensions) suggests you're looking for GPS.Entities `e` where `e.category()` is `"object"`.

Comment: I was hoping there was an existing Python module that would do this for me.  Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to learn the API to write my own.

Comment: I ended up looking for GPS.Entities `e` where `e.category()` is `"object"` or `"literal"` and `e.full_name()` is equal to the source filename + `e.name()`.  This gives me what I want and the only false positives I've seen are loop iterators used in elaboration routines.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention GPS, have you tried Tools->Documentation->Generate project?
This will generate html, with hyperlinks etc, similar to Javadoc.

Comment: I looked into this, but was hoping to avoid having to parse the html.  I really only want plain text.

Answer (score 2):

SciTools' [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/download/latest.php) product can extract this information, although it's rather pricey. Though if you're working with a mound of legacy code, it's well worth the money--it has saved my bacon on more than one occasion.